# Conversion process got success, but it showing transformation failed in oxygen (xml to json)

Tags: json, xml, xslt

While i'm performing xml to Json process using oxygen, i got the json files successfully in corresponding folders, but the oxygen saying transformation failed. Actually i'm converting single xml into 3 json files in the output, So anything problem in that

Xml file which i using:

```
<front>
  <Settings>
    <code>W3333</urlcode>
    <url>http://mlucenter.com/like/api</apiurl>
  </Settings>
</front>
<body>
  <Count>2</Count>
  <line>linear-gradient</line>
</body>
<back>
  <buttons>
    <button/>
  </buttons>
  <banner/>
</back>
```

I seperated front, body and back xml into front.json, body.json and back.json using below xslt:

```
line no: 46 <xsl:template match="front">
               var headerConfig = {
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
                       };
            </xsl:template>


 line no: 212   <xsl:template match="front">
               <xsl:result-document href="front.json">
                 <xsl:next-match/>
               </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
       <xsl:result-document href="body.json">
         <xsl:next-match/>
       </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="back">
       <xsl:result-document href="back.json">
         <xsl:next-match/>
       </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
```

I used saxon-PE 9.6.0.7 for transformation scenario and my output tab in oxygen as blank. Line no 46 defining other tags and line no 212 defining to convert. How i can give combinely

My error occuring in oxygen is

```
    Engine name: Saxon-PE 9.6.0.7
    Severity: warning
    Description: XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /MLU/selectReflect[1]/front[1] Matches both "element(Q{}front)" on line 212 of file:/D:/backup/Saf/Bramstein%20transforms%20XSL/Bramstein%20transforms.xsl and "element(Q{}front)" on line 46 of file:/D:/backup/Saf/Bramstein%20transforms%20XSL/Bramstein%20transforms.xsl
    URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTRE0540
.
.
.
```

Please suggest me, is that im doing right. Because the files converted well in the corresponding folder. Thanks in advance

Comment: The message is quite clear, you seem to have duplicate templates (line 212 and line 46) in your stylesheet (though may be doing the same thing)

Comment: It is a warning to inform you that your code contains two `xsl:template match="font"`, the processor uses the last one it finds in that case. So check your code on line 212 and line 46 and decide which template of the two you want, then remove the other or give it a low priority.

Comment: Thank You Martin and stefan, Its coming now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the two set of templates, i have combined into single set like below

```
line no: 46 <xsl:template match="front">
               var headerConfig = {
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
                       };
            </xsl:template>


 line no: 212   <xsl:template match="front">
               <xsl:result-document href="front.json">
                 <xsl:next-match/>
               </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:template>
```

I changed into

```
<xsl:template match="front">
               <xsl:result-document href="front.json">
                var headerConfig = {
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
                       };
               </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:template>
```